# Retrieving a list of rows with only a single item from other table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in Oracle database (10g express)

- product
- product_image

One product can have multiple images. Hence, there a one-to-many relationship from `product` to `product_image` and the `product_image` table has a foreign key that refers to the primary key of the `product` table.

I need to fetch a list of **products** with only a single image name in **each** row of the result set being retrieved regardless of the images being in the `product_image` table (even though there are no images for some of products).

The image name to be retrieved from the `product_image` table is *generally* the first image name in the `product_image` table after sorting each set of images for **each product** in ascending order. Something like the following.

```
prod_id    prod_name    prod_image

      1    aaa          aaa.jpg      //The first image name in the product_image table after sorting images for prod_id in ascending order.
      2    bbb          bbb.jpg      //Similar to the first case.
      3    ccc            -          //No image(s) found in the product_image table 
      4    ddd            -          //Similar to the previous case.
```

The general join statement for these two tables would be something similar to the following.

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_name, pi.prod_image 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_image pi 
ON p.prod_id=pi.prod_id;
```

Is this possible using a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL worked as mentioned in the question.

```
SELECT 
     p.prod_id,
     p.prod_name,
     t.prod_image 
FROM
     product p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
     SELECT 
           pi.prod_image_id,
           pi.prod_id,
           pi.prod_image 
     FROM
           product_image pi 
     INNER JOIN (
           SELECT 
                MIN(pi.prod_image_id) AS prod_image_id 
           FROM 
                product_image pi
           GROUP BY 
                pi.prod_id
     ) prod_image 
     ON pi.prod_image_id=prod_image.prod_image_id
)t ON p.prod_id=t.prod_id ORDER BY p.prod_id DESC;
```

Reference:

- [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/1391249)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can generate row number for each image per prod_id and use that. To return null or blank from missing product image you should use left outer join

```
WITH CTE AS
(

SELECT prod_id, DBMS_LOB.substr(prod_image,1,4000) prod_image, 
row_number() over (partition by prod_id order by prod_image) rn
FROM product_image
)

SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_name, nvl(pi.prod_image,'-') prod_image
FROM product p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE pi 
ON p.prod_id=pi.prod_id and pi.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Oracle responds - `ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing`. The column and table names in the database are similar to those you used in your answer.

Comment: @Tiny, updated my answer, i mistyped `AS` keyword after `CTE`

Comment: I have accepted my own answer just because it is general SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly I think the following query will work. I have not tested it.

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_name, MIN(DBMS_LOB.substr(pi.prod_image, 1))
FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_image pi 
ON p.prod_id=pi.prod_id 
GROUP BY p.prod_id, p.prod_name
ORDER BY p.prod_name;
```

Comment: Oracle responds - `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`. `pi.prod_image` is a `clob` type field in the database.

Comment: Replace the MIN(pi.prod_image) by the MIN(image name field)

Comment: The *image name field* is `prod_image` (in the database). Hence, it is the same as your answer `MIN(pi.prod_image)`.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is there any reason why your are using a CLOB field to hold a file name instead of varchar2?